# What is the role of left singular vectors in SVD?

Tags: singular-value-decomposition, vector-space

SVD decomposition of a data matrix $A$ of order $n \times d$ and rank $r$ can be expressed as follows

$$A_{n\times d} = U_{n\times r}D_{r \times r}V^{T}_{r \times d}$$

The rows of the data matrix $A$ are the *data points* in $d$ dimensional space. Thus, there are $n$ points in $d$ dimensional space.

The matrix $V$ contains $r$ *right singular vectors* as columns. Right singular vectors are [orthonormal](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/orthonormal-vectors) and forms a $r-$dimensional subspace that best fits the given $n$ data points.

The matrix $D$ is a diagonal matrix that contains *singular values*. Singular values signify the least squares (loss) of n-data points on the subspace $r$ right singular vectors.

The matrix $U$ contains *left singular vectors* as columns. Left singular vectors are also orthonormal.

But what does the $r$ left singular vectors signify?